# More elegant way of searching for pattern in this uint8 array

Tags: c

I am using C language in an embedded system. I have this uint8 array.

```
static uint8_t data_array[20];
```

Content of data_array is terminated with `'\n'`.

I want to check whether the first 3 bytes are "ABC". This is how I do it.

```
if (data_array[0]=='A' && data_array[1]=='B' && data_array[2]=='C')
{
    printf("pattern found\n");
}
```

Are there more elegant ways to detect the pattern? My method can be cumbersome if the pattern consists of 10 bytes.

Comment: `char` should be used for storing characters.

Comment: Does the code rely on a specific character set, ASCII, for example, or does it need be able to handle others?

Comment: @alk Good point. But as long as characters are used consistently,  the results will be valid. I'm pretty sure they must fit into range 0-127. Edit: it must fit into a `char`. So that range isn't even valid.

Comment: My concern is more about the implicit conversion from `int` (the `char` literals) to an 8-bit `unsigned`. Imagine an implementation for a platform with `CHAR_BIT == 9` and `'A' == 0b1 0100 0001`. @2501

Comment: @alk Yeah, see the comment edit above. ( uint8_t cannot exist with CHAR_BIT ==9 , but still, uint8_t may have trap values )

Comment: Ok, an explicity question: Are you after detecting any possible encoding of `char[3]={'A', 'B', 'C'}` or are you "just" after `char[3]={65, 66, 67}`?

Comment: Funny, how a deceptively simple question like this, requires several standard citations and/or assumptions to make a correct answer.

Comment: "*`uint8_t` cannot exist with `CHAR_BIT == 9`* sure? @2501

Comment: @alk Absolutely. uintN_t types must have no padding.

Comment: @2501: Well yes, fair enough. So then I see no more issues with the OP's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
static uint8_t data_array[20] = "ABC";
static uint8_t s[4] = "ABC";
static uint8_t length = 3;

uint8_t bool = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (s[i] != data_array[i]) {
        bool = 0;
        break;
    }
}
if (bool) {
    printf("pattern found\n");
}
```

[Live code here](http://ideone.com/k0SWuQ)

Comment: This `uint8_t s[4] = "ABC";` makes assumption which not necessarily are met on any implementation/platform.

Answer (score 0):

What about `strncmp()`?

```
static uint8_t data_array[20];

if(strncmp(data_array, "ABC", 3) == 0)
{
   printf("pattern found\n");
}
```

Comment: Does not need to be 0-terminated, because it's strNcmp.

Comment: `strncmp` doesn't require `0`-termination, only that (in this case) there are 3 bytes which can be read

Comment: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdjdZcWhEaFo0V1k) Works perfectly fine!

Answer (score -1):

```
char small='a' ,big='A';
int i=0;
char arr[10];

//To check 

for(i; i<10 ; i++)
{


    if(arr[i]==small || arr[i]==big)
    {
          //what you want to do 
    }
    small++;
    big++;



}
```

Comment: You are talking about `char`, the OP is using `uint8_t`.

Comment: ohh sorry I'm not familiar with uint8_t .

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize macros to generate code similar to your:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define TEST_FIRST_1(arr, c0)       ((c0) == *(arr))
#define TEST_FIRST_2(arr, c0, ...)  (TEST_FIRST_1(arr, c0) && TEST_FIRST_1((arr) + 1, __VA_ARGS__))
#define TEST_FIRST_3(arr, c0, ...)  (TEST_FIRST_1(arr, c0) && TEST_FIRST_2((arr) + 1, __VA_ARGS__))
#define TEST_FIRST_4(arr, c0, ...)  (TEST_FIRST_1(arr, c0) && TEST_FIRST_3((arr) + 1, __VA_ARGS__))
#define TEST_FIRST_5(arr, c0, ...)  (TEST_FIRST_1(arr, c0) && TEST_FIRST_4((arr) + 1, __VA_ARGS__))
/* continue, if need */


static unsigned char data[30] = {
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* true cases */
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_1(data, 1));
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_2(data, 1, 2));
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_3(data, 1, 2, 3));
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_4(data, 1, 2, 3, 4));
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_5(data, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    /* false cases */
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_5(data, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_4(data, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    printf("%d\n", TEST_FIRST_3(data, 0, 0, 0));

    return 0;
}
```

It may appear to be not clean at first look, but anyway doesn't lead to creating of an extra string literals for pattern to compare with.